# How to add a legend to a multi-figure plot?

Tags: r, plot, legend

The code below has been gleaned from various posters. I am just trying to add a simple legend in R and find that it's getting really complicated. When it's created, the text for Model1 and Model2 is far apart. I solved it with these lines:

```
plot_colors <- c("blue","red")
text <- c("Model1", "Model2")
xcoords <- c(0, 1.5)
secondvector <- (1:length(text))-1
textwidths <- xcoords/secondvector 
textwidths[1] <- 0
```

but then the box that encloses the legend is too small. I thought I solved that problem by first creating another legend (leg) with `plot=FALSE` and these lines (below) just to get the x,y coordinates for the box:

```
leg<-legend(x=-4, y=-240, legend=text, lty=1, cex=1.0, ncol=2, xpd=NA,col=c("blue", "red"),
       lwd=c(3,3),text.width=textwidths,plot=FALSE)
leftx <- leg$rect$left
rightx <- (leg$rect$left + leg$rect$w) * 1.2
topy <- leg$rect$top
bottomy <- (leg$rect$top - leg$rect$h) * 1.2
legend(x = c(leftx, rightx), y = c(topy, bottomy), legend=text, lty=1,
   cex=1.0, ncol=2, xpd=NA,col=c("blue", "red"),
   lwd=c(3,3),text.width=textwidths)
```

but now I get this error and not sure what it means.

> Error in xy.coords(x, y, setLab = FALSE) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ

Entire code is below:

```
#Error Analysis
DRP_1<-c(   3   ,   0   ,   -2  ,   NA  ,   NA  ,   -3  ,   -3  ,   -7  ,   3   ,   3   ,   0   ,   -6  )
Forecast_1<-c(  2   ,   2   ,   2   ,   11  ,   16  ,   16  ,   17  ,   16  ,   27  ,   27  ,   26  ,   22  )
DRP_2<-c(   -3  ,   -3  ,   -1  ,   NA  ,   NA  ,   6   ,   9   ,   16  ,   13  ,   10  ,   10  ,   16  )
Forecast_2<-c(  -2  ,   -4  ,   -6  ,   -17 ,   -33 ,   -49 ,   -66 ,   -82 ,   -109    ,   -136    ,   -162    ,   -184    )

DRP_1_AprMay<-c(    NA  ,   NA  ,   -2  ,   -2  ,   -3  ,   -3  ,   NA  ,   NA  ,   NA  ,   NA  ,   NA  ,   NA  )
DRP_2_AprMay<-c(    NA  ,   NA  ,   -1  ,   -1  ,   6   ,   6   ,   NA  ,   NA  ,   NA  ,   NA  ,   NA  ,   NA  )

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
par(mar=c(6,3,0,0.5))
par(mgp=c(2,0.25,0))
par(oma=c(0,1,3,0))
#
# CFE for Part 3315
#
g_range <- range(-7, DRP_1, Forecast_1,na.rm = TRUE)

plot(DRP_1, type="o", col="blue", ylim=c(-10,30), 
     axes=FALSE, ann=FALSE,lty=1)
axis(1, at=1:12, lab=c("Jan","","Mar","","May","","Jul","","Sep","","Nov",""))

axis(2, las=1,at=c(-10,0,10,20,30))

box()

lines(Forecast_1, type="o", pch=22, lty=1, col="red")

#Apr-May dashed lines

lines(DRP_1_AprMay,lty=2, col="blue")


abline(h = c(-10,0,10,20,30), lty = 2, col = "grey")
abline(v = 1:12,  lty = 2, col = "grey")
#abline(h = 0, lty = 1,lwd=1.5, col = "darkgrey")

title(xlab="Month in 2017", col.lab=rgb(0,0,0))
title(ylab="Cumuative Forecast Error (Number of Parts)", col.lab=rgb(0,0,0))

#
# PIS for Part 3315
#
g_range <- range(-184, DRP_2, Forecast_2,na.rm = TRUE)

plot(DRP_2, type="o", col="blue", ylim=c(-200,20), 
     axes=FALSE, ann=FALSE,lty=1)
axis(1, at=1:12, lab=c("Jan","","Mar","","May","","Jul","","Sep","","Nov",""))

axis(2, las=1,at=c(-200,-180,-160,-140,-120,-100,-80,-60,-40,-20,0,20))

box()
lines(Forecast_2, type="o", pch=22, lty=1, col="red")
#Apr-May dashed lines 

lines(DRP_2_AprMay,lty=2, col="blue")

abline(h = c(-200,-180,-160,-140,-120,-100,-80,-60,-40,-20,0,20), lty = 2, col = "grey")
abline(v = 1:12,  lty = 2, col = "grey")
#abline(h = 0, lty = 1,lwd=1.5, col = "darkgrey")
title(xlab="Month in 2017", col.lab=rgb(0,0,0))
title(ylab="Periods in Stock (Part-Months)", col.lab=rgb(0,0,0))

plot_colors <- c("blue","red")
text <- c("Model1", "Model2")
xcoords <- c(0, 1.5)
secondvector <- (1:length(text))-1
textwidths <- xcoords/secondvector 
textwidths[1] <- 0 
leg<-legend(x=-4, y=-240, legend=text, lty=1, cex=1.0, ncol=2, xpd=NA,col=c("blue", "red"),
       lwd=c(3,3),text.width=textwidths,plot=FALSE)
leftx <- leg$rect$left
rightx <- (leg$rect$left + leg$rect$w) * 1.2
topy <- leg$rect$top
bottomy <- (leg$rect$top - leg$rect$h) * 1.2
legend(x = c(leftx, rightx), y = c(topy, bottomy), legend=text, lty=1,
       cex=1.0, ncol=2, xpd=NA,col=c("blue", "red"),
       lwd=c(3,3),text.width=textwidths)
mtext(" Part 3315",outer=TRUE,side=3,cex=1.2,line=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you get is related to the fact that you pass 4 numbers to `x =` and two numbers to `y =` inside the `legend()` call.

You can resolve this by taking only one element from `leftx` and `rightx`:

```
legend(x = c(leftx[1], rightx[2]), y = c(topy, bottomy), legend=text, lty=1,
   cex=1.0, ncol=2, xpd=NA,col=c("blue", "red"),
   lwd=c(3,3), text.width=textwidths
)
```

But if you want a legend in that place a cleaner way of doing it might be to recapture the entire plotting region in a single frame:

```
par(fig=c(0, 1, 0, 1), oma=c(0, 0, 0, 0), mar=c(0, 0, 0, 0), new=TRUE)
plot.new()
legend("bottom", legend=text, lty=1, cex=1, ncol=2, xpd=TRUE, col=c("blue", "red"), lwd=3, bty="n")
```

And here is the result:

[image: picture]

In this case you will not need all those `leftx` and `rightx` variables.

I also noticed that you are not using some of the functionality that might be helpful in your situation. For example `grid()` to add the grey grid lines to the plot. The full code for a modified version might look something like this:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2), mar=c(6,3,0,0.5), mgp=c(2,0.25,0), oma=c(0,1,3,0))

# plot 1
plot.new()
plot.window(xlim=c(1, length(DRP_1)), ylim=c(-10,30))
grid(nx=length(DRP_1), ny=NULL)
box()
lines(DRP_1, type="o", col="blue")
lines(Forecast_1, type="o", pch=22, lty=1, col="red")
lines(DRP_1_AprMay,lty=2, col="blue")
axis(1, at=1:12, lab=c("Jan","","Mar","","May","","Jul","","Sep","","Nov",""), tck=-0.01)
axis(2, las=1, tck=-0.01)

title(xlab="Month in 2017", col.lab=rgb(0,0,0))
title(ylab="Cumuative Forecast Error (Number of Parts)", col.lab=rgb(0,0,0))

# plot 2
plot.new()
plot.window(xlim=c(1, length(DRP_2)), ylim=c(-200,20))
grid(nx=length(DRP_2), ny=NULL)
box()
lines(DRP_2, type="o", col="blue")
lines(Forecast_2, type="o", pch=22, lty=1, col="red")
lines(DRP_2_AprMay,lty=2, col="blue")
axis(1, at=1:12, lab=c("Jan","","Mar","","May","","Jul","","Sep","","Nov",""), tck=-0.01)
axis(2, las=1, tck=-0.01)

title(xlab="Month in 2017", col.lab=rgb(0,0,0))
title(ylab="Periods in Stock (Part-Months)", col.lab=rgb(0,0,0))

# legend
par(fig=c(0,1,0,1), oma=c(0,0,0,0), mar=c(0,0,0,0), new=TRUE)
plot.new()
legend("bottom", legend=c("Model1", "Model2"), lty=1, cex=1, ncol=2, xpd=TRUE, col=c("blue", "red"), lwd=3, bty="n")
```

With the following result:

[image: picture2]

Comment: Thank you, but I find just specifying "bottom", drops the legend too far down.  I was hoping I could adjust the location by specifying the x,y coordinates like x=-4, y=-240, as I had done previously and it worked.  It doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @Angus Before calling a legend I change the par to have `fig=c(0, 1, 0, 1)`. This means that the new plot frame was created with x and y axis extending up to 1. Try `legend(x=0.5, y=0.05, ...)` and it should work.

Comment: Alternatively add a parameter `inset=c(0, 0.03)` to the legend call with `x="bottom"`. It will move the legend up in y direction by 3 %.